# Hard coding the order clauses ? Or offering a sort parameter?

Tags: rest, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have a design question:

Should I hard code the **order by** clause in the query statements?

```
public Page<Admin> search(String searchTerm, Pageable page) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page.getPageNumber(), page.getPageSize());
    return adminRepository.search(searchTerm, pageable);
}

@Query("SELECT a FROM Admin a WHERE LOWER(a.firstname) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) OR LOWER(a.lastname) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) OR LOWER(a.email) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) OR LOWER(a.login) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) ORDER BY a.lastname ASC, a.firstname ASC")
public Page<Admin> search(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, Pageable page);
```

Or, should I let the choice to the end user:

```
public Page<Admin> search(String searchTerm, Pageable page) {
    return adminRepository.search(searchTerm, page);
}

@Query("SELECT a FROM Admin a WHERE LOWER(a.firstname) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) OR LOWER(a.lastname) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) OR LOWER(a.email) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')) OR LOWER(a.login) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%'))")
public Page<Admin> search(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, Pageable page);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subjective question that is not usually welcome on SO. Anyhow, I would leave the things like **ordering**, **sorting** to the client. In this is way it is more robust. It might be the case that different users have different criteria for ordering.

Comment: Design is often subjective. Anyway, leaving the sorting to the client leaks something out across all layers. In terms of encapsulation it's blasphemy. I still feel like hard coding it in the JPQL statement.

Comment: is really up to you. To understand the mindset I had when given the response: imagine an application that provides a grid with information to a given client, multiple columns. You hardcode the sorting on the back-end. The client want's to see the records with the highest/lowest column12 value, but because you hardcoded it...he/she cannot do it

Comment: I totally agree with your use case. I shall leak out the sorting to the client only if the use case mandates a multiple columns sorting options. Otherwise the sorting will stay in the JPQL statement.

Comment: couldn't agree more. You mean the default sorting

Comment: Yes, the entity default sorting. But a JPQL statement having this default sorting should not be passed a sort argument by the pageable parameter. Using such a query, the argument passed to the page parameter must not contain any sort clause. That is, the argument must look like: new PageRequest(0, 10); And not look like: Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "lastname"), new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "firstname")); new PageRequest(pageIndex, pageSize, sort); Otherwise there would be a conflict between the order by clause in the @Query and the sort order in the argument.